# What are two good unicode characters I can use to represent "Likes" and "Dislikes"?

Tags: icons

I'll be displaying YouTube Like/Dislike ratings for videos in a text-based format, so I'm using unicode's vast icon codepages as a way to display various things (such as star ratings, using [U+2605 BLACK STAR](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2605/index.htm) ★★★★★) for example.

My first thought to displaying likes/dislikes with a unicode icon was with thumbs up/down icons, however unicode lacks a THUMBS UP or THUMBS DOWN code point. What's the next best choice to display "Like" or "Dislike" from possible unicode codepoints?

Edit to clarify: I need a two unicode characters that best represent the ideas of Like and Dislike. Those characters will be displayed next to the number of Likes and Dislikes respectively.

Comment: I think it is good idea to show as Like/dislike instead of a icon. Just my thought

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you want here - do you need a charachter to replace the stars from YouTube ratings, or a character that you press to like or dislike?

Comment: [](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f44d/index.htm)  [](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f44e/index.htm)

Comment: @PatrickMcElhaney - great find! Do these symbols show up for you though - they don't in any browser I have...

Comment: @RogerAttrill They show up in Safari on OS X Lion ( [thumbs up](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f44d/index.htm)  / [thumbs down](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f44e/index.htm) )

Comment: @PatrickMcElhaney Not showing up in Chrome/Windows 7 here.

Comment: @PatrickMcElhaney Great find, looks like this was just added to the unicode spec a year ago - which sadly, explains the lack of font support. Maybe I'll be able to use those codepoints in a few years :(

Comment: Be careful with localisation! Hand signals can mean very different things in different cultures. Apparently the thumbs up signal is very rude in some places (see http://www.slideshare.net/NirmalaPadmavat/hand-gesture-of-differents-cultures )

Answer (score 12, accepted):

2611/12 ballot box with check / X

### ☑ ☒

2639/a white smiling/frowning face

### ☺ ☹

261d/f white up/down pointing index

### ☝ ☟

Comment: For some reason the two smiley symbols don't look like a pair on most browsers I tried - despite being adjacent in the unicode sequence. Additionally - all the symbols look slightly different on almost every browser I tried (the big 5) on Windows 7 with Safari looking the worst.

Comment: Probably because the concave-up stroke of Mr. Smiles fits better above the chin than the concave-down stroke of Mr. Grumps.

Answer (score 9):

**Thumbs up** (U+1F44D), **Thumbs down** (U+1F44E)

These aren't implemented in most fonts yet, unfortunately. But eventually they'd be a good choice.

Answer (score 8):

Likes column title with + and - indicators.